# how to pass checked event to button click in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf

i have option button binded to some property and everything is working fine but now i want to achieve same thing on button click .
is there any way to pass click event to button click?my option button xaml code is as follows

```
<RadioButton Content="Any connection"
    x:Uid="saifeconnect.settings.autoconnectto.any.radiobutton"
    Margin="0,5"
    GroupName="AutoConnect"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=AutoConnectMode,
      Mode=TwoWay,
      Converter={StaticResource enumConverter},
      ConverterParameter=kAny}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible then make use of RelayCommand. Follow the given tutorial, best for RelayCommand. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute